# Finding Error in Digit Counting Loop

Tags: java, loops

We have as an exercise the task of finding errors in the following loop. The task of the loop is to output the number of digits of a number before the ".", i.e. "32782.12" would be equal to 5. Now so far, I really do not see any error. The only thing that is the case is that an input = 0 would not lead to a correct answer - do you have me any hint?

```
public class countingDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double number = 88888888.99;

        for(int digits=0; digits<6; ++digits) {
            if (number*number < 1) {
                System.out.println("The number has  " + digits + " digits");
                break;
            }
            number /= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the number of digits in the sample value. Now look at the maximum number of times the loop can execute...

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but consider this in the future: `Number of digits of a number = log_base_a(number) - 1`, where `a` is the base of the number (10 with decimal numbers, 2 with binary, etc).

Comment: @Manu343726 For n = 10, log 10 - 1 = 0...

Comment: Is it necessary to hard code loop range ?  In example , loop range shouldn't be 8 ?

Comment: @Manu343726 to be exact, `ceil(log a (number))` if I remember correctly...

Comment: @ppeterka66 exactly, thanks. But I cannot change the comment yet :)

Answer (score 2):

Is is not unusual to handle the special cases separately:

- 0
- -0 (where applicable...)
- maximum value of datatype (Double.MAX_VALUE)
- minimum value of datatype (Double.MIN_VALUE)
- etc.

So I'd handle `0` this way:

```
if(number==0.0 ) {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void countingDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    double number = 88888888.99;

    if (number == 0){
      System.out.println("The number has  1 digits");
    }else {
       for(int digits=0; digits<20; ++digits) {
           if (number < 1) {
               System.out.println("The number has  " + digits + " digits");
               break;
           }
            number /= 10;
       }
    }

  }
```

Comment: The original code was chekcing only upto 6 characters. However the double range is much higher than that. I put 20 to cover the entire range. Wasn't sure of the exact range so chose 20 to cover it.

Comment: is not possible to use simple while loop ? Why for loop with hard coded range values ?

Comment: Actually there's no need to use any loop. It can be find out by simply taking the log base 10 of the number, and then the upper bound.